# Replace strings in a vector of text no packages

Tags: r, string, gsub

I have 2 vectors:

```
Param<-c("alpha","beta","theta")
Trend<-c("b","c","ac","bc")
```

I want to replace every item of Trend vector with the items in Param vector, being "a" the first element (alpha), b the second (beta), and so on...

The desired result would be:

```
Result=("beta","theta","alphatheta","betatheta")
```

If possible i dont want to use any package, if not any idea is welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option with `str_replace` from `stringr` which can take a named vector for replacement

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(Trend, set_names(Param, letters[1:3]))
#[1] "beta"       "theta"      "alphatheta" "betatheta"
```

---

Or if we dont' want to use any packages, use `gsub` in a loop

```
lts <- letters[1:3]
for(i in seq_along(lts)) Trend <- gsub(lts[i], Param[i], Trend)
Trend
```

Comment: Many thanks for your solutions, i prefer no to use any packages since im gonna generate a lot of jpg pictures and need to save memory

Comment: @DavidRicardoMenachoVadillo i updated with a solution with no packages